# Railsチュートリアル第3章のコードをサーバーにデプロイするとエラーが発生します

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsチュートリアル第3章を進めていて最後のルーティングの設定をしていたのですが、コードをそのまま同じファイルに同じように打ったにもかかわらずサーバーを立ち上げて確認すると

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

という文言が出てきて正常にページが表示されませんでした

ルートファイルとコントローラーは以下の通りです

#### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'static_pages/help'
  get 'static_pages/about'
end
```

#### static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

チュートリアルのリスト3.33あたりから変になったのかと考えています。

どなたかこのエラーの原因もしくは治し方がわかる方いらっしゃったらご教授お願いします

Comment: stackoverflowへようこそ。
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
とあるので、さらなる情報を得るために、ログを見てみてはどうでしょう（そして見てもわからないのであれば、ここに追記してみましょう）。　また参考にしているページのリンクも載せるとなおよくなると思います。

Comment: shingo.nakanishiさんも書いているように、"We're sorry, but something went wrong."のメッセージではなく、サーバーで出力されているログを載せてもらった方が早く解決できます。（具体的なエラー内容はログに出ているはずなので）あと念のため確認ですが、そのコードはローカルではちゃんと動いていますか？